# In which scenario I should use Authentication link from Web App Azure Portal and in which scenario I have to use MSAL Library

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I want to Authenticate user using Azure AD.
I had application registration in Azure AD and everything is set up ,I am using Authentication link from Azure Portal Web app settings section.
According to Microsoft dcoumentation MSAL library is recommended
when to use MSAL library and when to use Azure Portal Authentication
Azure Portal => Settings=> Authentication.

[image: Authentication setting from Azure Portal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication link from Web App Azure Portal is [Easy Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization).

It does not conflict with whether you use [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview).

You can take a look at [Why use the built-in authentication?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#why-use-the-built-in-authentication).

An important reason is:

> The built-in authentication feature for App Service and Azure
> Functions can save you time and effort by providing out-of-the-box
> authentication with federated identity providers, allowing you to
> focus on the rest of your application.

When you enable Easy Auth, Azure will create an app registration which represents your web app. Any attempts to access your web app will require sign-in with your Azure AD account.

You can also use the app registration Azure created for you (or create your own app registration without enabling Easy Auth) to configure with MSAL. MSAL is a mature framework and you can find the following benefits [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview).

Easy Auth uses [**Implicit Flow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) by default to sign in. If your web app requires other auth flows (eg. [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)), using MSAL would be a better choice.